# Excel: How to split a sentence in a cell into columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently have a string of text in a single excel cell that looks like this:

> Customer: xxxProject Name & Number:1247893Project Summary: in store
> ice creamProjected Annual Value:  USD$20,2323Customer’s Application /
> Brand:  bird brandProduct Code and Name: 23431348 CaramelValue
> Proposition: Product quality and flexible supplySales Account Manager:
> tommy

How do i split this string of continuous text into multiple columns in excel with an output that looks like this?

| Customer | Project Name & Number | Project Summary | Annual Value | Customer's Application/Brand | Product Code and Name | Value Proposition | Sales Account Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | 1247893 | in store ice cream | USD$20,2323 | bird brand | 23431348 Caramel | Product quality and flexible supply | tommy |

Ive tried using a code that looks something like this:

`=MID(J3, SEARCH(":",J3) + 1, SEARCH(":",J3,SEARCH(":",J3)+1) - SEARCH(":",J3) - 22)`

but its pretty manual as i have to type it multiple times

Answer (score 1):

### Split (Column of) Strings By Multiple Delimiters (Excel Formula)

[image]

- You could split the string by the titles but that forces you to keep them fixed.

```
=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT($A2,$B$1:$I$1&":",,TRUE))
```

- Therefore it would be preferable to use a list of the delimiters (titles) in another worksheet:

[image]

- Then you could use the following:

```
=TRIM(TEXTSPLIT($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9&":",,TRUE))
```

- To spill the results also across rows, you could do the following:

```
=LET(Data,A5:A6,Delimiters,Sheet2!A2:A9&":",
    DROP(REDUCE("",Data,LAMBDA(rr,r,
VSTACK(rr,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(r,Delimiters,,TRUE))))),1))
```

- Note that you can do the same for the first formula.

Comment: No `VBA` Sir seems like you are very much fascinated about the new Excel Functions. Good we all like those formulas. Thank you very much for the share =)